# can we have the array of dict in tcl?

Tags: tcl

Is that possible to create a array of dict in tcl?
array contains elements "a, b ,c"
   In the array element "a" contains some value & is pointing to dict contains {key , value }
   In the array element "b"  contains some value & is pointing to dict contains some {key ,value}
   similar for "c" also

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be done:

```
(1)% set myarray(a) [dict create user john password iforgot]
user john password iforgot

(2)% set myarray(b) [dict create user trish password samehere]
user trish password samehere

(3)% parray myarray
myarray(a) = user john password iforgot
myarray(b) = user trish password samehere

(4)% # Get password for user in slot a
(5)% dict get $myarray(a) password
iforgot
```

## Discussion

A dict is just an ordinary list, which is fine for an array's value. In this case, I have an array `myarray` with two indices, `a` and `b`.

## Update

You can also using dict of dict:

```
set master [dict create]
dict set master a [dict create user john password iforgot]
dict set master b [dict create user trish password samehere]
```

You can also use `Tclx` keyed list:

```
(97)% package require Tclx

(98)% keylset db a.name john a.password iforgot b.name trish b.password samehere

(99)% puts $db
{a {{name john} {password iforgot}}} {b {{name trish} {password samehere}}}

(100)% keylkeys db
a b

(101)% keylget db a
{name john} {password iforgot}

(102)% keylget db a.name
john
```

The nice thing about keyed list is the keys can be nested: `a.name`, `a.password`, ...